# Adding values in MySQL rows

Tags: mysql, logging, grouping, algebra

I have a table where I store parsed server logs:

```
mysql> SELECT id,date,message_type FROM log_entry LIMIT 10 ;                 
+----+---------------------+--------------+
| id | date                | message_type |
+----+---------------------+--------------+
|  1 | 2015-01-08 18:13:15 |            2 |
|  2 | 2015-01-08 18:13:14 |            1 |
|  3 | 2015-01-08 18:13:12 |            1 |
|  4 | 2015-01-08 18:13:11 |            1 |
|  5 | 2015-01-08 18:13:11 |            1 |
|  6 | 2015-01-08 18:13:11 |            1 |
|  7 | 2015-01-08 18:13:10 |            1 |
|  8 | 2015-01-08 18:13:08 |            1 |
|  9 | 2015-01-08 18:13:07 |            1 |
| 10 | 2015-01-08 18:13:06 |          512 |
+----+---------------------+--------------+
```

Each log is classified by its **message_type**. I can also group them by hour:

```
mysql> select DAY(date) as day, HOUR(date) as hour, message_type, count(message_type) FROM log_entry WHERE date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH AND message_type BETWEEN 1 AND 4 GROUP BY day,hour,message_type ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 3;
+------+------+--------------+---------------------+
| day  | hour | message_type | count(message_type) |
+------+------+--------------+---------------------+
|    8 |   18 |            1 |                 177 |
|    8 |   18 |            2 |                  61 |
|    8 |   18 |            4 |                  14 |
+------+------+--------------+---------------------+
```

In this example, on the 8th day and the 18th hour of a certain date, I have  **177** entries with a message_type of 1, **61** with type 2 and **14** with type 4.

I would like to get the following calculation for every hour:

```
type(1) - type(2) - type(4)
```

Which in this case would return

```
+------+------+--------------+---------------------+
| day  | hour | result                             |
+------+------+--------------+---------------------+
|    8 |   18 | 102                                |
+------+------+--------------+---------------------+
```

I'm doing this is because I want to create a chart showing hourly activity on a server I'm running. A type 1 entry means someone connected, a type 2 means there was a graceful disconnect and a type 4 means there was a timeout.

Is this a feasible thing to do in the database or should I do this on the application layer?

Comment: What should trigger such calculation? What should be done with the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `SUM()` function and `CASE` statement to count each message_type and do the math.

```
SELECT   DAY(date) as day, HOUR(date) as hour,  
         SUM(CASE WHEN message_type = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) -
         SUM(CASE WHEN message_type = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) -
         SUM(CASE WHEN message_type = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as result
FROM     log_entry 
WHERE    date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH 
         AND message_type BETWEEN 1 AND 4 
GROUP BY day,hour;
```

Comment: I was getting funky results but it's because you have an extra "group by message type" at the end. Apart from that, your answer is perfect, thanks!